# WCF ServiceLayer class redirect to metadata. Why?

Tags: c#, wcf, metadata

I have a solution with three projects in C#:

- CareLife.DataLayer ( Class Library )
- CareLife.ServiceLayer ( WCF Service Application)
- CareLife.BusinessLayer ( Serive Library )

I added the .dll (located obj folder) of project CareLife.BusinessLayer in the CareLife.ServiceLayer because of need to access methods of BusinessLayer in the project ServiceLayer.

```
namespace CareLife.BusinessLayer.Operations
{
    public class SpecialityServices
    {
        void GetArea() { }
    }
}
```

and....

```
namespace CareLife.ServiceLayer
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class SpecialityOperations
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="Area", Method="GET")]
        ICollection<Area> GetArea()
        {
            try
            {
                SpecialityServices specialityServices = new SpecialityServices();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {            
                throw;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The question is: WHY when I *Go to definition* in the ServiceLayer of class SpecialityServices, I always am redirect to metadata class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding it as a project reference instead of a dll from the obj folder ?

Answer (score 0):

The resource I see defined here is Area. Are you doing a GET on http://`<serviceRoot`>/Area ?

Also, if you're building a rest service, why not use WebAPI?

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly declare webHttp endpoint. Here is sample `system.serviceModel` config section:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
           <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
            <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
           </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
           <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
           </serviceBehaviors>
           <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
             <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
           </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
           <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Just to clarify, i am adding `endpointBehaviors` section and `webHttp endpoint` to service section